# Google Task API No More Shows Tasks created via API on Calendar

Tags: google-tasks-api, google-tasks

When creating tasks via API those tasks do not appear in calendar, but are only visible in sidebar section of tabs.
[image: ap]
Just few days ago all seems to be working correctly, so this could be some bug or their sudenn change. How to find that? How to notify google api of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Closing as the issue is already been filled.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133809207